# mysql innotop not working - use of unitiialized value

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin, mysqladministrator

Installed innotop 1.10.0 on centos7 mysqlversion is 5.7.12.  When i run innotop in centos server and option T selected it gives me the use of unintiaized value error how do i fix it.

```
WThread  Waiting Query  WWait  BThread  BRowsMod  BAge  BWait  BStatus
```

Blocking QueryUse of uninitialized value in list assignment at /usr/bin/innotop line 5818.

Comment: can anyone help me out regarding this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yum update innotop  solved the issue.